# ¿Cómo seleccionar nodo específico dentro de documento XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Si en un documento XML existe más de un nodo con el mismo nombre 
¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el segundo o tercer nodo  con sintaxis Xpath?

Comment: Hola Efrain **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Seleccionar uno con XPath**

Para seleccionar el 2do, en particular si estás usando [`XmlNode.SelectSingleNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
(//Nodo)[2]
```

- El `[]` tiene mayor precedencia que el `//`, por eso se usa el paréntesis.

---

**2. O usar un XPath más específico**

Pero muchas veces, los nodos con el mismo nombre tienen ancestros diferentes, que permiten seleccionar cada uno con búsquedas diferentes. Por ejemplo:

```
//PadreA/NombreNodo
```

```
//PadreB/NombreNodo
```

- Más info de sintaxis XPath en [Operadores y caracteres especiales (XPath)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

**3. Desde el código en C#**

Se pueden obtener todos los nodos que coinciden con un XPath usando [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/es/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx), y acceder a cada elemento de la colección.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.Load("archivo.xml"); 

//NamespaceManager  para resolver cada namespace
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable); 
nsmgr.AddNamespace("nombre_namespace", "urn:URI_de_namespace"); 

//Seleccionar todos los nodos que coinciden
XmlElement elementoPadre = doc.DocumentElement; 
XmlNodeList nodeList = elementoPadre.SelectNodes("//NombreNodo", nsmgr);

//bucle en cada uno
foreach (XmlNode nodo in nodeList){ 
    //Hacer algo con nodo
}

//o directamente acceder al 2do
Console.WriteLine(nodeList.Item(1).InnerXml);
```

Answer (score 2):

Te falta aclarar más la pregunta, pero creo que dices algo así.

tienes un xml:

```
<padre>
  <hijo>
    <datos>
      <cumple>1</cumple>
    </datos>
  </hijo>
  <hijo>
    <datos>
      <cumple>2</cumple>
    </datos>
  </hijo>
</padre>
```

y deseas obtener el primer cumpleaños con XPath, Tienes varias maneras:

Pendiente de los parentesis

1. `(/padre/hijo/datos/cumple)[1]`
2. `(/*/*/*/cumple)[1]`   #más corto pero menos descriptivo
3. `/padre/hijo[1]/datos/cumple` #es la mejor opción por ser semánticamente correcta

En todo caso evita usar `//` porque es computacionalmente más costoso, hace una prueba recurrente en todo el documento

aca una web donde puedes validar tu XPath https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html